# how to run two different neural network on two GPUs?

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu

I have two GPU but only one is in use now for model training, so how can I run another neural network on the other GPU?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using pytorch, and have CUDA installed, you can use their `.to()` function

A simple example on the pytorch documentation shows:

```
>>> tensor = torch.randn(2, 2)  # Initially dtype=float32, device=cpu
>>> tensor.to(torch.float64)
tensor([[-0.5044,  0.0005],
        [ 0.3310, -0.0584]], dtype=torch.float64)

>>> cuda0 = torch.device('cuda:0')
>>> tensor.to(cuda0)
tensor([[-0.5044,  0.0005],
        [ 0.3310, -0.0584]], device='cuda:0')

>>> tensor.to(cuda0, dtype=torch.float64)
tensor([[-0.5044,  0.0005],
        [ 0.3310, -0.0584]], dtype=torch.float64, device='cuda:0')

>>> other = torch.randn((), dtype=torch.float64, device=cuda0)
>>> tensor.to(other, non_blocking=True)
tensor([[-0.5044,  0.0005],
        [ 0.3310, -0.0584]], dtype=torch.float64, device='cuda:0')
```

You can refer to these links here:

https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.to
https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/cuda.html#torch.cuda.device

Comment: So it just need me to assign the task on the gpu I want to use?

Comment: Yes, that's one method. Another method I forgot to mention is you can use the ```CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES``` method, though I've only used in on linux systems.

Example:

```$ CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=1 python3 train_model.py```

This sets the environment variable to only detect the 2nd GPU (they start from id 0 normally, e.g 0,1,2..) and you should be able to run your code as it is